# Java - Checking if int is empty

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to do field validation for an int in android studio. The code for the field is as follows;

```
public class Register extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etName, etAge, etUsername, etPassword;
    Button bRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bRegister:
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                String ageText = etAge.getText().toString();
                if(! TextUtils.isEmpty(ageText)) {
                    int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText);
                }

                if(name.length()==0)
                {
                    etName.requestFocus();
                    etName.setError("Please don't leave the name field empty.");
                }else if(username.length()==0)
                {
                    etUsername.requestFocus();
                    etUsername.setError("Please don't leave the username field empty.");
                }else if(password.length()==0)
                {
                    etPassword.requestFocus();
                    etPassword.setError("Please don't leave the password field empty.");
                }/*else if(age == null)
                {
                    etAge.requestFocus();
                    etAge.setError("Please don't leave the age field empty.");
                }*/
                else if(!name.matches("[a-zA-Z]"))
                {
                    etName.requestFocus();
                    etName.setError("Please only use alphabetic characters");
                }else{
                    User user = new User(name, age, username, password);
                    registerUser(user);
                }


                break;
        }
    }

    private void registerUser(User user) {
        ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(this);
        serverRequest.storeUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(User returnedUser) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I can't get the int age validated, it keps giving me this error;

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

User class

```
public class User {
    String name, username, password;
    int age;

    public User(String name, int age, String username, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String ageText = etAge.getText().toString();
int age = 0;

if(! TextUtils.isEmpty(ageText)) // If EditText is not empty
    age = Integer.parseInt(ageText); // parse its content to integer

// Continue validation...
```

instead of

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
```

Comment: It's making this line not work, because it needs t have an int; User user = new User(name, age, username, password);

Comment: Use the integer `age` variable, not the **string** variable `ageText`. What type of parameters does the `User` constructor accept ?

Comment: Updated the OP with the USer class. I am using the int age variable, but it cannot resolve the symbol.

Comment: Can you show your full code where you declare these variables & validate the input ? The problem has something to do with these variables' visibility.

Comment: @JorenPolfliet You've written `int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText);` and Mohammed wrote `age = Integer.parseInt(ageText);` .. why have you changed his suggestion?

Comment: @Tom +1; you need to declare `age` outside of the `if` block.

Comment: Now I get, 'Variable age might not have been initialized'

Comment: @JorenPolfliet Since I can't see his older version, I don't know how it looked like. But please use his newer version instead.

Comment: Replaced the code with the newer version, see error from my last comment.

Comment: @JorenPolfliet You need to initialize the `age` variable before you try to use it (when you create the `User`). Since it is possible that `! TextUtils.isEmpty(ageText)` is false and `age` won't be set there, you need to do something. You have 2 ways: either do, what Mohammed does in his _newer_ version, or add `else` on `if(name.length()==0)`. You also have a third way, but that looks a bit silly, so you shouldn't do that anyway. Choose one of the two ways.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
String ageString = "25"; //age will be null if it is empty or not a number
Integer age = null;
try {
    age = Integer.parseInt(ageString);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}

if (age == null) {
    //enter age
}
```